# IE 9 Crashes while recording Scripts using Vugen 9.51

Tags: loadrunner

IE 9 Crashes while recording Scripts using Vugen 9.51. I am using 64 bit windows 7 operating system.

Please suggest me any solution for this.

Thanks & Regards,
Phani.

Comment: When specifically does it crash? On init? during recording? Does it crash on all sites? Some, but not others?

Comment: It is happening during recording and it is happening for IE only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two issues in play, both conditions are covered as part of the installation requirements

- 64 bit operating system, 32 bit vugen.  See release notes on recording 64 bit applications.     Crossing the WOW32 divide usually does not end well for a 32 bit app trying to control a 64 bit one.  Going the other way is typically cleaner.
- Version of Browser.  Always check the version of the browser supported and never use an unsupported version.  Doing so places you in a questionable supported mode in your testing environment which should be hardened from items which have unknown performance or quality.

Comment: Thanks James it seems like i need to install LR11.5 to support IE 9

Answer (score 1):

There is a known incompatibility between the recording mechanism in LR 9.5X (bbhook) and newer versions of IE (8 and above) this issue was fixed in LoadRunner versions 11 and up. Please upgrade your version of LoadRunner or record with the supported versions of IE for LR 9.5X.

As far as I know we didn't release a fix for bbhook for LR 9.5X.

You can download a trial version of LoadRunner 11.52 from the HP website. The following link explains how:
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/Download-HP-LoadRunner-and-enhance-your-experience-with-the-tips/ba-p/5969843#.UwWu4fmSyk4

Thanks,
Boris.

Comment: Thanks Boris will install LR 11.52.